# Add another dropdown button to own devexpres PopupContainerEdit with same style behaviour

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

We've got custom `PopupContainerEdit` that inherits from DevExpress'es `PopupContainerEdit`. One of our custom features is another dropdown button (`EditorButton` with kind = `ButtonPredefines.Glyph`) that acts like the default one except, it opens different `PopupContainerControl`. Everything works as intended except button's style coloring. The button acts like default button - that means it doesn't support state coloring (checked/unchecked) when dropdown is visible/hidden. I couldn't find any custom draw event/method for `EditorButton`.

Is it possible to achieve such behaviour? If so, how?

@edit

[image: Example]

Simple example of the above situation.

- Default `PopupContainerEdit` looks like image A. When you click on the
  button (triangle like), dropdown shows and button goes into checked
  state.
- Our `PopupContainerEdit` (that inherits from default) looks like
  B.
- C, D is coloring example when you hover the button.
- E is checked state coloring for default button (it works like that by
  DevExpress'es design).
- F is our button behaviour - acts like normal button.
- G is what we want - checked state coloring for our button

Our approach to create custom button:

```
string TheToolTipText = "The text";
string OurButtonTag = "TheButton";
Image TheIcon = new Image(); // just example ...

EditorButton customButton = new EditorButton();
customButton.Width = 16;
customButton.Image = TheIcon;
customButton.ToolTip = TheToolTipText;
customButton.Tag = OurButtonTag;
customButton.Kind = ButtonPredefines.Glyph;
this.Properties.Buttons.Add(customButton);
```

To be honest there's nothing more to show. We're not aware of any custom Draw event or similar things.

Comment: Can you add some code & pictures?

Comment: @nempoBu4 Added some code and image that illustrates the siutation.

Comment: A similar topic for the VCL version of DevExpress ist discussed in [Q402967](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q402967/changing-the-behaviour-of-multiple-buttons-on-tcxcombobox).

Answer (score 3):

There are two properties in `RepositoryItemPopupContainerEdit` that are responsible for this behavior. Fisrt one is [`RepositoryItemPopupBase.ActionButtonIndex`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemPopupBase_ActionButtonIndextopic) property. It's value specifying which editor button will open the editor's dropdown window. The second one is [`RepositoryItemPopupContainerEdit.PopupControl`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemPopupContainerEdit_PopupControltopic) which sets the control to display in the popup window. So, by manipulating with this two properties, you can achieve the desired behavior.

Here is example:

**0. `RepositoryItemPopupContainerEdit` descendant**

Because you need to show two different `PopupContainerControl`
you can create additional properties for each of your controls in your custom `RepositoryItem`.

```
public class RepositoryItemCustomEdit1 : RepositoryItemPopupContainerEdit
{
    #region Some default stuff for custom repository item (constructors, registration, etc).
    static RepositoryItemCustomEdit1() { RegisterCustomEdit1(); }
    public const string CustomEditName = "CustomEdit1";
    public RepositoryItemCustomEdit1() { }
    public override string EditorTypeName { get { return CustomEditName; } }
    public static void RegisterCustomEdit1()
    {
        Image img = null;
        EditorRegistrationInfo.Default.Editors.Add(new EditorClassInfo(
            CustomEditName, 
            typeof(CustomEdit1), 
            typeof(RepositoryItemCustomEdit1),
        //For v13.2 you need to use custom ViewInfo class. So, here is CustomEdit1ViewInfo.
        //For v15.1 you can use the base PopupContainerEditViewInfo.
            typeof(CustomEdit1ViewInfo),
            new ButtonEditPainter(), 
            true, 
            img));
    }
    #endregion

    #region Hide base PopupContainerControl properties in designer.
    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public override PopupContainerControl PopupControl
    {
        get { return base.PopupControl; }
        set { base.PopupControl = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public override int ActionButtonIndex
    {
        get { return base.ActionButtonIndex; }
        set { base.ActionButtonIndex = value; }
    }
    #region

    #region First PopupContainerControl properties
    public int DefaultActionButtonIndex { get; set; }
    public PopupContainerControl DefaultPopupControl { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Another PopupContainerControl properties
    public int DifferentActionButtonIndex { get; set; }
    public PopupContainerControl DifferentPopupControl { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public override void Assign(RepositoryItem item)
    {
        BeginUpdate();
        try
        {
            base.Assign(item);
            RepositoryItemCustomEdit1 source = item as RepositoryItemCustomEdit1;
            if (source == null) return;

            DefaultActionButtonIndex = source.DefaultActionButtonIndex;
            DefaultPopupControl = source.DefaultPopupControl;

            DifferentPopupControl = source.DifferentPopupControl;
            DifferentActionButtonIndex = source.DifferentActionButtonIndex;
        }
        finally
        {
            EndUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

You can see new properties in your designer:
[image: Designer]

**1. `PopupContainerEdit` descendant**

Now you can use this properties in your custom `Edit` class.

```
public class CustomEdit1 : PopupContainerEdit
{
    #region Some default stuff for custom edit (constructors, registration, etc).
    static CustomEdit1() { RepositoryItemCustomEdit1.RegisterCustomEdit1(); }
    public CustomEdit1() { }
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public new RepositoryItemCustomEdit1 Properties { get { return base.Properties as RepositoryItemCustomEdit1; } }
    public override string EditorTypeName { get { return RepositoryItemCustomEdit1.CustomEditName; } }
    #endregion

    protected override bool IsActionButton(EditorButtonObjectInfoArgs buttonInfo)
    {
        int buttonIndex = Properties.Buttons.IndexOf(buttonInfo.Button);

        if (buttonIndex == Properties.DefaultActionButtonIndex ||
            buttonIndex == Properties.DifferentActionButtonIndex)
        {
            //Set the Properties.ActionButtonIndex value according to which button is pressed:
            Properties.ActionButtonIndex = buttonIndex;

            //Set the Properties.PopupControl according to which button is pressed:
            if (buttonIndex == Properties.DefaultActionButtonIndex)
                Properties.PopupControl = Properties.DefaultPopupControl;
            else
                Properties.PopupControl = Properties.DifferentPopupControl;

            return true;
        }

        return false;                
    }
}
```

**2. `PopupContainerEditViewInfo` descendant**

For v13.2 you need to use custom `ViewInfo` class for your editor:

```
public class CustomEdit1ViewInfo : PopupContainerEditViewInfo
{
    public CustomEdit1ViewInfo(RepositoryItem item) : base(item) { }

    public new RepositoryItemPopupBase Item { get { return base.Item as RepositoryItemCustomEdit1; } }

    //Show the pressed state when button is pressed or when popup is open.
    protected override bool IsButtonPressed(EditorButtonObjectInfoArgs info)
    {
        var hitObject = PressedInfo.HitObject as EditorButtonObjectInfoArgs;

        return
            (hitObject != null && hitObject.Button == info.Button) ||
            (IsPopupOpen && Item.ActionButtonIndex == info.Button.Index);
    }
}
```

**Result**

In the result you will get something like this:

[image: DefaultPopupControl] and [image: DifferentPopupControl]

Comment: What DevExpress do you use? I can't see any ActionShowPopup method neither in my code or DE documentation. Did you mean ShopPopup?

Comment: @user2475983 My version is 15.1.7. I'm just overriding the method which is protected. You can find this method if you press F12 on `PopupContainerEdit` word in your code and after press it on `PopupBaseEdit` then you will see the `protected virtual void ActionShowPopup(EditorButtonObjectInfoArgs buttonInfo);` between other members of `PopupBaseEdit` class. Also if you type the `override` keyword then auto-complete will show this method in the list of available methods to override.

Comment: Our version is 13.2 and when I try to add `override` declaration such method as ActionShowPopup doesnt show in the list. Hitting F12 redirects me to the method I just added.

Comment: @user2475983 I have updated the code for `CustomEdit1`. It seems, that there are no problem with overriding `IsActionButton` method in v13.2. Try this.

Comment: @user2475983 Finally, I've got it. Also for v13.2 you need to use custom `ViewInfo` class to check the pressed state of your button. I have updated my answer.